# jquery load function not working consistently

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So I created this PHP script that utilizes a long polling technique. It waits for about 15 seconds, and if any of the variables that are stored in the MySQL database change from the ones stored as session variables, it updates them and ends the script.

on the client side, once the Ajax script is over, I used the load function to refresh certain parts of the page to reflect the new session variables.

It all works fine when I use two different computers to test the website. But if I use two different browsers on the same computer, the load function ceases to work. For example, if I load up the website first on Chrome, the load function works. If I then simultaneously open it up on Torch (another browser), the load function only works for Torch. If I close Torch, the load function works again on Chrome.

Is there any particular reason for this?

this is what the javascript looks like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../process_joinGame.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result);
    }


});

$("#gamecontainer").load("game.php #gamecontainer", function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error") {
        alert("Error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);

    } else {
        alert("Text loaded!");

    }

});

setTimeout(urlCheck, 3000);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all, you need to wrap them inside DOM ready `$(function(){ /* your code */ });`

Comment: Yep, that worked!

Formerly, the load function in my code was looking for a div that hadn't loaded up yet. DOM ready allows for that part of the page to load up before refreshing it again. (I think?)

Anyway, thanks a ton!

Comment: Yes, that's correct. And you're welcome!